# What does the error for "Invalid value for prop `value` on <select>" mean in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been building a trivia game using the Open Trivia API and I am getting an error that I have been trying to figure out but am stuck on. It says: Invalid value for prop `value` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.
I will include my code pages. Thank you in advance for you help.

App.js page:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import Questions from './components/questions'
import CategorySelector from './components/CategorySelector'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      selectedCategory: null

    }
    this.selectedCategory = this.selectedCategory.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    axios
      .get('https://opentdb.com/api_category.php')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.setState({
          categories: response.data.trivia_categories
        })
      })
  }

  selectedCategory (category) {
    this.setState({ selectedCategory: category })
  }

  render () {
    const { categories, selectedCategory } = this.state

    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h2>Trivia Game</h2>
        {
          selectedCategory
            ? <Questions selectedCategory={selectedCategory} />
            : (
              <CategorySelector
                categories={categories}
                onSelect={event => selectedCategory}
                selectedCategory={this.selectedCategory}
              />
            )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

CategorySelector.js page:

```
import React from 'react'

class CategorySelector extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { categories, selectedCategory, onSelect } = this.props
    return (
      <div className='CategorySelector'>
        <select
          value={selectedCategory} onChange={onSelect}
        >
          <option value=''>-- No category selected --</option>
          {categories.map(category => (
            <option value={selectedCategory} key={category.id}>{category.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CategorySelector
```

Question.js page

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      currentQuestionIndex: 0

    }
    this.handleNextQuestion = this.handleNextQuestion.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const qUrl = `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=3&category=${this.props.selectedCategory.id}`
    axios
      .get(qUrl)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.setState({
          questions: response.data.results
        })
      })
  }

  handleNextQuestion () {
    this.setState({ currentQuestionIndex: this.state.currentQuestionIndex + 1 })
  }

  render () {
    const { selectedCategory } = this.props
    const { questions, currentQuestionIndex } = this.state
    const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    let answers = []
    if (currentQuestion) {
      answers = currentQuestion.incorrect_answers.concat([currentQuestion.correct_answer])
    }

    return (
      <div className='Questions'>
        <h2>{selectedCategory.name} Questions</h2>
        {currentQuestion && (
          <div>
            <h3>{currentQuestion.questions}</h3>
            <div>
              {answers.map((answer, index) => <p key={index}>{answer}</p>)}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        {(currentQuestionIndex < questions.length - 1) &&
          <button onClick={this.handleNextQuestion}>Next Question</button>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Questions
```

Comment: I forgot to include this part in the error message:     in select (at CategorySelector.js:8)
    in div (at CategorySelector.js:7)
    in CategorySelector (at App.js:43)
    in div (at App.js:37)

Comment: you have State, Method and Prop all named `selectedCategory` . No wonder you got them confused. Try to use different names. Like `selectCategory` for method. At least ! :D . To the `<CategorySelector` you pass the prop as the `selectedCategory` method and the onChange method as `selectedCategory` state :) . Invert that

Answer (score 1):

While passing the prop, you're referring the state variable as `this.selectedCategory`

Change this line

`selectedCategory={this.selectedCategory}`

to

`selectedCategory={selectedCategory}`